# HTML Overlay pass-through screen implementation

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, tailwind-css

I am tying to implement a Draggable overlay screen(initially positioned at the bottom half) that passes through another screen. An example of how I would like it to look is as described here - https://medium.com/@iamWaseem99/how-to-make-swipable-draggable-overlay-views-in-swift-xcode-82a86adece9c.

Disclosure regarding the tools currently being used - TailwindCSS for styling, HTML, CSS and JS via the Stimulus JS framework.

Current approach - I have installed Hammer JS and was attempting to achieve this by tracking the "panup" event and adjust the height of both the divs to seem as through the bottom screen was passing through. This ended up being messy, was wondering if there is a cleaner approach to achieve this.

I have found a React library - https://github.com/manufont/react-swipeable-bottom-sheet, however I am currently not using the React framework so was wondering if there are any alternatives through which this can be achieved.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the two links in your question i made a solution with Hammer.js but with "swipe" and *top* instead of "panup" and *height*. I don't know what is messy for you, but this is imo very clean:

```
hammerOverlay.on('swipe', (e) => {
    overlay.style.top = ( e.deltaY < 0 ) ? 0 : (window.innerHeight - triggerHeight) + 'px';
});
```

**Working example:**

```js
const overlay = document.querySelector('#overlay');
const triggerHeight = document.querySelector('#trigger').clientHeight;
const hammerOverlay = new Hammer(overlay);

hammerOverlay.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL });
hammerOverlay.on('swipe', (e) => {
    overlay.style.top = ( e.deltaY < 0 ) ? 0 : (window.innerHeight - triggerHeight) + 'px';
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
    
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: #ddd;
    transition: top 300ms;
}
    
#trigger h3 {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="overlay">
        <div id="trigger"><h3>Swipeable bottom sheet</h3></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want an arrow like that in your first link, here is a solution with css arrows:

```js
const overlay2 = document.querySelector('#overlay2');
const triggerHeight2 = document.querySelector('#trigger2').clientHeight;
const hammerOverlay2 = new Hammer(overlay2);

hammerOverlay2.get('swipe').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL });
hammerOverlay2.on('swipe', (e) => {
    if( e.deltaY < 0 ) {
        overlay2.style.top =  0;
        overlay2.querySelector('.arrow').classList.remove('up');
        overlay2.querySelector('.arrow').classList.add('down');
        
    }
    else  {
        overlay2.style.top = (window.innerHeight - triggerHeight2) + 'px';
        overlay2.querySelector('.arrow').classList.remove('down');
        overlay2.querySelector('.arrow').classList.add('up');
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
    
#overlay2 {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: #ddd;
    transition: top 300ms;
}
    
#trigger2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid black;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.up {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="overlay2">
        <div id="trigger2"><i class="arrow up"></i></div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to achieve the pull up/down effect when the 'trigger' is clicked, but still doesn't give the effect I would like which is slowing changing height based on the swipe up distance. Is there something additional that needs to be done?

Comment: I think that could be possible, but that is answered in another question ;)> So if your original question is now answered you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Oh this was actually my intent behind asking this question. In case this is answered in a different question, could you please point me to that answer?

Comment: If this was your intent you should have asked for that. At least should the two links have shown the desired behaviour. But both is not the case. Therefor you should ask a question about changing height depending on swipe speed (or something similar)...

Comment: Ok will create a new question, thanks for clarifying and taking a shot at answering this question :)